# How to edit the content of a mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was modding my minecraft when I realised that I have a lot of items and blocks that my computer couldn't handle any more mods! I realised that most of the items are useless for me! I have tried to delete some of them but as soon as I wanted to start working I realised that I have no idea how to do it!

For example in (Mrcrayfishs furniture mod) there are only two or three items that I realy want and to make the mod smaller. Is there any possible way to do it without using any special programs? If there is no such way please tell me the way you would do it?

My question is can you do it or not and how can I achieve that?

Comment: Shouldn't this go to the game dev's stack exchange?

Comment: You need src code for the mod or some sort of API.

Comment: @camelCase altgough I agree with you, I don't understand why this question has recieved 4 downvotes in 9 hours. It's tottally off topic, but there is nothing he can do about it at this point. He can't delete, its just here. After 1 or 2 downvotes why continue with that when its not helping?

Comment: @AshwinGupta - Doesn't it need 3 downvotes to get auto-deleted?

Comment: @AshwinGupta The point of downvotes isn't for the asker.  It's for other readers, to signal to them that it's not worth their time to look at this question.  They're not meant as a signal to the asker, other than as a judgement of the quality.

Comment: @Frank ok fair enough. Well explained.

Answer (score 3):

In general, to modify a computer program (and even a modification of another program, which mods are) you need to be a programmer and know source code of that program. In other words, first you need to learn to **make** mods, then you can learn to **alter** others' ones. Makers of some mods leave some things to be more easily switched around by users via "configuration files", but most do not bother.

So, no, you generally can't turn off parts of mods.